# Automatically Open Terminal on start OR New Window

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Simple question: 99% of my time spent in VSCode is spent with a terminal open.  Is there a setting or an extension that will keep terminal open when I either

A. Start VSCode

OR

B. Open a file / folder in a new window

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of batch files?
Create a text file with the extension .bat and insert this code to make it open both programs with one user action. Do change the Visual Studio path so it matches your executable location; the example is generic.

```
start cmd && "C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
```